# Dynamically load components inside *ngFor in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive, mat-tab

I studied [the code available on angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader), and I replicated it in my scenario with a `mat-tab-group`. However, I would like to be able to use the ad-host directive inside a `*ngFor`. I tried it, and the directive is always `undefined`.

I searched here and, while there are several questions addressing this problem, I found no clear example on how to do this. The idea is that I have a `mat-tab-group` composed of several `mat-tabs`, which are loaded through a `*ngFor` directive. In each tab I would like to show a different component according to the selected index. Is there any way to achieve this?

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sm8vag) is my modified stackblitz: as you can see it literally says `this.adHost is undefined` in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the way you get a reference to your `adHost`.

```
@ViewChild(AdDirective, {static: false}) adHost: AdDirective;
```

It needs to be `static: false` (see [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)) because it's rendered dynamically by `mat-tab`, so it's not always in the template.

And don't call `loadComponents` in `ngOnInit`, since the view has not been rendered yet, so `adHost` will be undefined.  Use `ngAfterViewInit` for instance. I just commented it.

[Corrected stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sm8vag-gbhwrg)

**Edit**

Following your clarifications, I changed quite a lot of things 
(removed your `setInterval`, used `@ViewChildren` instead of `ViewChild`, use `ngOnChanges` to know when to render the data, etc.).

Here is the [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sm8vag-cjl3g2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fad-banner.component.ts)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work the way I would like it to work. Maybe I have explained it poorly, bu the idea was to get a Component in each of the tabs, so if the first tab contains a HeroProfileComponent I should show a HeroProfileComponent in the first tab content, if the second is a HeroJobAdComponent it should show a HeroJobAdComponent inside, and so on and so forth.
In your example, only the first tab shows the content, whereas the other ones remain empty. Note that if I move the `ng-template` outside the `mat-tab-group`, everything works, but I do not think that is a good approach.